# Step into nuget-package code c# via resharper

Tags: c#, .net-core, resharper

Im trying to step into a service method during debug, that is defined in an nuget-package that i have installed:

```
var persons = await service.GetPersonsByRole(42, null, null); // This method is from the installed nuget-package
```

Im trying to do this with resharper. However, when I try to step in via F12, i don't get to the implementation of the method. Instead I get to the implementation of the return type of the service:
[image]

If i hit F11, it just skips over the method, instad of into it. Why can't I reach the impementation of the service?

Comment: well, stepping **into** a method is done by using F11

Comment: well, if i hit F11, it just skips over it, and not into it.

Comment: Have you made sure to follow these steps? (I assume this is what you are asking for) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Debugging_Without_Source_Code.html#debugging

Comment: I only get that the implementation of the service was not found